# JPQL update with select

Tags: sql, oracle, jpql

I'm trying to convert Native query to JPQL and I have problem with UPDATE with select.

```
UPDATE DocumentBody PP SET PP.prepaidLeft = PP.prepaidLeft + (SELECT R.amount 
FROM ReferencePrepaymentDocument R WHERE PP.documentBodyId = 
R.prepaymentDocumentBodyId AND R.documentHeaderId=:NaglDokRozchID) WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT R.amount FROM ReferencePrepaymentDocument R WHERE PP.documentBodyId = 
R.prepaymentDocumentBodyId AND R.documentHeaderId=:NaglDokRozchID)
```

I tried with JOIN like this:

```
UPDATE DocumentBody PP SET PP.prepaidLeft = PP.prepaidLeft + amount JOIN 
(select R.amount from ReferencePrepaymentDocument R where PP.documentBodyId = 
R.prepaymentDocumentBodyId and R.documentHeaderId=:NaglDokRozchID) amount ON 
PP.documentBodyId = R.prepaymentDocumentBodyId  where exists (select R.amount 
from ReferencePrepaymentDocument R where PP.documentBodyId = 
R.prepaymentDocumentBodyId and R.documentHeaderId=:NaglDokRozchID)
```

But I get " operator or WHERE expected, got 'JOIN' ".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, the error message is right. It's `update x set y = z where whatever` (`z` can be  a subquery). The first version looks OK, after a little formatting for human readability. What do you need it to do?

Comment: I have to convert the first block of code to JPQL. SELECT in UPDATE dosen't work for me

Comment: I'd never heard of JPQL but I don't see any mention of either subqueries or joins  in the [syntax documentation](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_bulk_ops), so you could be out of luck, sorry.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your time :)